# tomcat 7 - session got deleted when server restarts

Tags: session, tomcat

I have 2 different tomcat servers (different machines)
after creating x sessions on each of them,
when i restart both ,
one of them keeps the sessions while the other didn't,

Any ideas why? I wish to keep sessions on both tomcats

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The most likely way session persistence has been disabled is be editing `$CATALINA_BASE/conf/context.xml`. If the following has been uncommented, persistence will be disabled.

```
<Manager pathname="" />
```

Note that the same entry could be added to a web application's context.xml file so you'll need to check those (if they exist) too.